# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (beginning coder)

Tags: python, mcedit

I need help with this:

```
structureRegion = box
blocks = 0
for x in xrange(structureRegion.minx,structureRegion.maxx):
    for y in xrange(structureRegion.miny,structureRegion.maxy):
        for z in xrange(structureRegion.minz,structureRegion.maxz):
            if blockAt(x, y, z, level) != 0 or air:
                blocks = blocks + 1
for block in blocks:
    for x in xrange(structureRegion.minx,structureRegion.maxx):
        for y in xrange(structureRegion.miny,structureRegion.maxy):
            for z in xrange(structureRegion.minz,structureRegion.maxz):
                coords2 = []
                coords2.append((x,y,z))
                part1 = ''.join(coords)
                part2 = ''.join(coords2)
```

When I do use this, I get the error above in the title.

I just wanted to go through each block until there are no more and repeat the code.

Thanks

(This is for Minecraft and for an MCEdit filter by the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[...]
for block in xrange(blocks):
[...]
```

Shorter (and with some other mistakes fixed):

```
coords2 = []

for x in xrange(box.minx,box.maxx):
    for y in xrange(box.miny,box.maxy):
        for z in xrange(box.minz,box.maxz):
            if blockAt(x, y, z, level) != 0:
                coords2.append((x,y,z))

part1 = ''.join(coords)
part2 = ''.join(coords2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`blocks` is an integer, but the line `for block in blocks:` tries to treat it as though it's [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) (a list, set, tuple, etc.), which it's not, hence the error.